# I'm a time traveller! You are too!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've just earned the Solstice hat! Huzzah! And I see that several others have earned it as well.

Now as far as I know from reading its requirement, that hat is earned by posting a comment on 12/21. Today is 12/20 in UTC time. What's up with this? Is it a bug? Have I discovered time travel? Should I not be pointing this out so that I can keep the hat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had I done my homework, I'd have easily found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/262980) meta.SE post. But let's put it here for all the others that might be tempted to ask the question.

Time-based hats are given a leeway of about 12 hours before and after the UTC day. That's to allow people in different parts of the world to fulfill the requirements during that day where they are on Earth. Since it's extra work to check where someone is and calculate the limits for them, everyone gets an extra 24 hour window. Yay! Thanks SE team!